# Getting error interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not map[string]string - Why does it fail

Tags: json, dictionary, go, struct

Why does the following statement fail:

```
// type of fileData --> type PackageJson map[string]interface{}

dep, fDep := fileData["dependencies"]
if fDep {
    // Following Line Fails
    version, fVer := dep.(map[string]string)[packageName]
}
```

The above statement throws an error:

```
 interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not map[string]string [recovered]
```

Here:

- `dep` is of type `interface{}`
- With the statement `dep.(map[string]string)[packageName]`, am I not telling that `dep` is a map with key as string and value as also the string?  Does it mean different?

Comment: I'd like a thorough explanation from someone as to why, as well, but short answer is that go doesn't allow type assertions for member types like that. The standard workaround is to loop over the collection and cast every member individually

Comment: @SuhailGupta interface variables have __two types__: the _static type_ (or just type), and a distinct _dynamic type_, which is the (non-interface) type of the value assigned to the variable at run time (unless the value is the predeclared identifier nil, which has no type). Type assertions are about asserting the dynamic type of the interface value; in other words, you need to specify the correct dynamic type if you want the type assertion to succeed. So, while the variable `dep` may be of type `interface{}`, the value assigned to it is of type `map[string]interface{}` not `map[string]string`.

Answer (score 1):

An interface value is two things: a data type, and a data value of that type. Type assertions like `dep.(X)` returns the value stored in the interface `dep` if that value is of type `X`.

So, based on the error, you can see that the value stored in dep is a `map[string]interface{}`, and not `map[string]string`. That's why type assertion fails.

Based on the code, I believe there is a tacit expectation that you want to get a string value from that map. As I said before, an interface contains a value in it, so once you recovered the value contained in `dep`, then you can access the value of a key, which is also an `interface{}`, and then access the value in that. So:

```
k,ok:=dep.(map[string]interface{})[packageName]
if ok {
   str, ok:=k.(string)
   if ok {
      // k is a string, and str is the string contained in `packageName` key in the map
   } else {
      // k is not a string
   }
}
```

Comment: But isn't `dep` of type `interface{}`? If it is why are we doing `map[string]interface{}`?

Comment: As I said, and interface has a value and a type. The type of `dep` is `map[string]interface{}`.